# NestJS Service returning all files in a directory

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I am working on a service in NestJS to return all the files in a working directory.  NestJS is the latest, and my Node install is 14.12.0.

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

import * as fs from 'fs';

@Injectable()
export class FileService  {

    constructor(
        private Configuration:ConfigService     // This service is just to set the working directory, where I have files
    ) { }

    public GetFileListing(Directory?:string):Observable<string[]> {
        const Results:Array<string> = new Array<string>();
        

//      fs.readdir(Configuration.DataDirectory, (err, files) => {
        fs.readdir('/c/users/xxx/datafiles/./', (err, files) => {
            files.forEach( file => {
                console.log(file);
                Results.push(file);
            });
        });
        return of(Results);
    }
}
```

However, instead of reading the data and returning the list of files, the function generates an error:

```
[ExceptionHandler] Cannot read property 'readdir' of undefined
```

Changing to a hard set path does not work, although I can use the terminal window in VSCode and do a `ls /c/users/xxx/datafiles/./` and get a list of the files I expect.

Changing to `import * as fs from 'fs';` gets rid of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the `fs` module uses named exports instead of a default, so you need to do

```js
import * as fs from 'fs';
```

instead of

```js
import fs from 'fs';
```

Comment: I changed the code.  Your change does get rid of the unhandled exception, but the function does not work still.  I had found examples that indicated after Node 10, you did not need the `import * as fs from 'fs';` just use `import fs from 'fs';`, but it does appear to solve one part of the problem.

Comment: So what error do you run into now? Are you just not returning what you expect? You may be returning the result too quickly, and if that's the case then you should wrap the `fs.readdir` in an observable instead of pushing the results to an array and returning an observable of the results

Comment: I guess the lack of data is due to the simple loop I was using to show the first error. I will likely need to move this to a Promise or Observable to give time for the actual data reads.